# Read appsettings.json keys in methods other than Main Program.cs .NetCore 3.1 console app

Tags: .net-core, console-application, appsettings

Basically I have to call a REST API from a .netcore console app which will return me some xml and then this console app will need to create a csv file from that xml.
I need to keep the REST API url and csv path in my appsettings.config.
I have created two keys for that.

Now I don't want to read these keys in my main method but I am building ConfigurationBuilder in my main method and therefore its available only in Main method.
Code in my Main method looks like below.

```
 configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
.AddEnvironmentVariables()
 .Build();
```

where configuration is **static IConfiguartion configuration = null** at Program.cs class level.
For now I have made this ConfigurationBuilder as a class level static variable , initilaizing it in Main then reading it elsewhere but not sure if its a good approach or there's some better way of doing this?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: A good approach is probably dependency injection, unluckily you are in a console application, but it is still easy to set up (https://andrewlock.net/using-dependency-injection-in-a-net-core-console-application/). Then you can register your `IConfiguration`, from now on it is ready to be used inside the constructor of the classes that need it. A better approach would be following the options pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use Dependency Injection like described in @Marco Luzzaras comment.

But if it is not possible in you scenario you can also access the same configuration by encapsule everything in a [Singleton](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/singleton-design-pattern-in-C-Sharp/)

```
public class ConfigurationProvider 
{
    private static IConfiguration _instance;
    public static IConfiguration Instance 
    {
        get 
        {
            if(_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                    .Build();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

... and use it everywhere you need it.

[dotnet fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sN1mIu)

Comment: Thanks to all who took time to answer :)